# Getting projected map coordinates with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gps, location, maps

Longitude, latitude position 10.38938, 60.12116 is 243910, 6673846 in UTM 33N (projected with Proj.4): http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/32633/

Is it possible to get the same result using d3.geo.transverseMercator?

I'm able to translate latitude, longitude into screen coordinates:
http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2013/11/showing-gps-tracks-in-3d-with-threejs.html

But I'm not sure how to set the configuration methods to get UTM coordinates.

I could use Proj4js, but I would like to get rid of this dependency if it's possible with D3.js.

Comment: D3 will only project to screen coordinates.